# Cannot use mod_wsgi-express to serve a site on https

Tags: ssl, https, django, mod-wsgi

I have a django site. I downloaded letsencrypt certificates for mysite.com and tried to run mod_wsgi-express like this:

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server --log-to-terminal --startup-log --https-port 443 --https-only --server-name mysite.com --ssl-certificate-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/cert.pem --ssl-certificate-key-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem --ssl-ca-certificate-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem --user www-data --group www-data --port 80 --host mysite.com
```

But I received the following error:

```
AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed
AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed
SSL Library Error: error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate -- No CAs known to server for verification?
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: From which end did you get that error?

Comment: @MichaelHampton From the terminal, while running mod_wsgi_express. I have activated logging to terminal.